# htaccess match more then 10

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello iam trying to match more then 10 variables in my htaccess  , but after the 10th variable it doesnt recognize and begin with the first $1 - but i expect "$11" not $1

Browser Url: http://localhost/s/adobe+cs5/58058,18793/111/666/

> htaccess Rewrite: `Array ( [search] => adobe cs5 [categories] => Array ( [0] => 58058 [1] => 18793 [2] => ) [pricefrom] => 111 [priceto] => adobe cs51 [email] => adobe cs53 )`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /eule2/
RewriteRule ^s/([^/\.]+)/(([0-9]+)(,([0-9]+?))?(,([0-9]+?))?/)(([^/]+)/)?(([^/]+)/)?(([^/]+)/)?((?<email>[^/]+)/)?$ 
search.php?search=$1&categories[]=$3&categories[]=$5&categories[]=$7&pricefrom=$9&priceto=$11&email=$13 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few unnecessary optional capturing groups in your regex. You can convert "optional groups" to non-capturing groups i.e. `(?:...)` to bring count of capturing groups to less than 10.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^s/([^/.]+)/(\d+)(?:,(\d+?))?(?:,(\d+?))?/(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?$ search.php?search=$1&categories[]=$2&categories[]=$3&categories[]=$4&pricefrom=$5&priceto=$6&email=$7 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will handle this URL:

```
http://localhost/s/adobe+cs5/58058,18793/111/666/adobe+cs53/
```

to populate these `GET` parameters in `search.php`:

```
Array
(
    [search] => adobe cs5
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58058
            [1] => 18793
            [2] => 
        )
    [pricefrom] => 111
    [priceto] => 666
    [email] => adobe cs53
)
```

Comment: OK sure, but what if the matches *were* all necessary? How do you reference a match after the 9th? In JS this seems to work, but in .htaccess `$10` and onwards result in the concatenated value of `$1` + `0`.

Comment: For capturing more than 9 values we will have to break out rule in 2 parts since we cannot anything above $9

Comment: Aha interesting. Thanks.